# Trigger jquery plugin onclick automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery plugin that shows a hidden div and animate when you click the button. I've used the jquery.fn prototype.

This is the jquery plugin

```
 (function($) {
            'use strict';
            $.fn.launchBtn = function(options) {
               var mainBtn, panel, clicks, settings, launchPanelAnim, closePanelAnim, openPanel, boxClick, panelBody, panelMedia;
               mainBtn = $(".proactive-chat-button");
               panel = $("#proactive-chat .panel");
               panelMedia = $("#proactive-chat .panel-media");
               panelBody = $("#proactive-chat .panel-body");
               clicks = 0;
               //default settings
               settings = $.extend({
                  openDuration: 600,
                  closeDuration: 200,
                  rotate: true
               }, options);
               //Open panel animation
               launchPanelAnim = function() {
                  $(panel).removeClass('swift-out');
                  $(panelMedia).removeClass('swift-out');
                  $(panelBody).removeClass('swift-out');
                  panel.animate({
                     opacity: "show",
                     width: "show",
                     height: "show",
                  }, settings.openDuration);
                  $(panel).addClass('swift-in');
                  $(panelMedia).addClass('swift-in');
                  $(panelBody).addClass('swift-in');
                  panelMedia.animate({
                     opacity: "show",
                     width: "slideDown",
                     height: "slideDown",
                     transitionDelay: "0.1s"
                  }, settings.openDuration);

                  calculate();
                  $('.proactive-chat-button').addClass('shadow-3');

               };
               //Close panel animation
               closePanelAnim = function() {
                  $(panel).removeClass('swift-in');
                  $(panelMedia).removeClass('swift-in');
                  $(panelBody).removeClass('swift-in');
                  $(panel).addClass('swift-out');
                  $(panelMedia).addClass('swift-out');
                  $(panelBody).addClass('swift-out');
                  panel.animate({
                     opacity: "hide",
                     width: "hide",
                     height: "hide"
                  }, settings.closeDuration);
                  panelMedia.animate({
                     opacity: "hide",
                     width: "slideDown",
                     height: "slideDown",
                     transitionDelay: "0.02s"
                  }, settings.openDuration);
                  $('.proactive-chat-button').removeClass('shadow-3');
                  $('.modal-overlay').fadeOut(100);
               };
               //Open panel and rotate icon
               openPanel = function(e) {
                  if (clicks === 0) {
                     if (settings.rotate) {
                        // $('.proactive-chat-icon').removeClass('rotateBackward').toggleClass('rotateForward');
                     }
                     launchPanelAnim();
                     clicks++;
                  } else {
                     if (settings.rotate) {
                        //$('.proactive-chat-icon').removeClass('rotateForward').toggleClass('rotateBackward');
                     }
                     closePanelAnim();
                     clicks--;
                  }
                  e.preventDefault();
                  return false;
               };
               //Allow clicking in panel
               boxClick = function(e) {
                  e.stopPropagation();
               };
               //Main button click    
               mainBtn.on('click', openPanel);
               //Prevent closing panel when clicking inside
               panel.click(boxClick);
               $('.proactive-chat-icon').click(function() {
                  $('.proactive-chat-icon .procty').toggleClass('proactive-procty-close').toggleClass('proactive-procty');
               });
               $('.panel-heading-button').click(function() {
                  if (clicks === 0) {
                     if (settings.rotate) {
                        // $('.proactive-chat-icon').removeClass('rotateBackward').toggleClass('rotateForward');
                        $('.proactive-chat-icon .procty').toggleClass('proactive-procty-close').toggleClass('proactive-procty');
                     }
                     launchPanelAnim();
                     clicks++;
                  } else {
                     if (settings.rotate) {
                        //$('.proactive-chat-icon').removeClass('rotateForward').toggleClass('rotateBackward');
                        $('.proactive-chat-icon .procty').toggleClass('proactive-procty').toggleClass('proactive-procty-close');
                     }
                     closePanelAnim();
                     clicks--;
                  }
               });
               $(document).click(function() {
                  closePanelAnim();
                  if (clicks === 1) {
                     $('.proactive-chat-icon .procty').toggleClass('proactive-procty').toggleClass('proactive-procty-close');

                  }
                  clicks = 0;
               });
            };
         }(jQuery));
```

and to use that I've called the method launchBtn()

```
 $("#proactive-chat").click().launchBtn({
                    openDuration: 250,
                    closeDuration: 300
                 });
```

My concern is I want to trigger it automatically when an interval or condition is met. I've used $('#proactive-chat').trigger('click') ​however it doesn't work. Is there any way I can trigger it automatically? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click()` returns the jQuery object and thus your function is never called on a click event. If you want it to fire during clicks you need to add a handler function as a parameter to `click()` like so:

```
$("#proactive-chat").click(function(){
    $(this).launchBtn({
        openDuration: 250,
        closeDuration: 300
    });
});
```

In this form `.trigger('click')` should work, although I don't quite understand why you would use the `$.fn` prototype when you don't reference `this` anywhere in your plugin. This could have been a simple function.